# From ... ago with past simple

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

Does the sentence “Max knew Dave from some years ago”
mean the same as
“Max has known Dave for some years”
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The meanings of the two statements are close but not identical.

Let's assume that Max and Dave were at university together 10 years ago but haven't made contact since.

Then you are likely to state that:

> Max knew Dave from some years ago

However, if Max and Dave have been long-standing neighbours, you might say:

> Max has known Dave for some years

The first statement implies that there has been a substantial break in their relationship. The second implies that there has been a steady relationship up until the present.